# Accessing Google Docs with GData

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, gdata-api, google-docs

Working Platform: ASP.NET 4.0 C# ( Framework Agnostic )

Google GData is my dependency

```
using Google.GData.Client;
using Google.GData.Extensions;
using Google.GData.Documents;
```

I have two pages Auth and List.

Auth redirects to Google Server like this

```
public ActionResult Auth()
{
    var target = Request.Url.ToString().ToLowerInvariant().Replace("auth", "list");
    var scope = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/";
    bool secure = false, session = true;

    var authSubUrl = AuthSubUtil.getRequestUrl(target, scope, secure, session);
    return new RedirectResult(authSubUrl);
}
```

Now it reaches the List Page if Authentication is successful.

```
public ActionResult List()
{
    if (Request.QueryString["token"] != null)
    {
        String singleUseToken = Request.QueryString["token"];

        string consumerKey = "www.blahblah.net";
        string consumerSecret = "my_key";
        string sessionToken = AuthSubUtil.exchangeForSessionToken(singleUseToken, null).ToString(); 

        var authFactory = new GOAuthRequestFactory("writely", "qwd-asd-01");
        authFactory.Token = sessionToken;
        authFactory.ConsumerKey = consumerKey;
        authFactory.ConsumerSecret = consumerSecret;
        //authFactory.TokenSecret = "";
        try
        {
            var service = new DocumentsService(authFactory.ApplicationName) { RequestFactory = authFactory };

            var query = new DocumentsListQuery();
            query.Title = "project";

            var feed = service.Query(query);
            var result = feed.Entries.ToList().ConvertAll(a => a.Title.Text);
            return View(result);
        }
        catch (GDataRequestException gdre)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

This fails at the line `var feed = service.Query(query);` with the error

> Execution of request failed: https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full?title=project

The `HttpStatusCode` recieved on the catch block is `HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized`

What is wrong with this code? Do I need to get TokenSecret? If so how?

Comment: Have you tested the query you are trying to execute with client authentication? Just to rule out any fault on that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used the [3-legged OAuth in the Google Data Protocol Client Libraries](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/auth/oauth.html)

Sample Code

```
string CONSUMER_KEY = "www.bherila.net";
string CONSUMER_SECRET = "RpKF7ykWt8C6At74TR4_wyIb";
string APPLICATION_NAME = "bwh-wssearch-01";

string SCOPE = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/";

public ActionResult Auth()
{
    string callbackURL = String.Format("{0}{1}", Request.Url.ToString(), "List");
    OAuthParameters parameters = new OAuthParameters()
    {
        ConsumerKey = CONSUMER_KEY,
        ConsumerSecret = CONSUMER_SECRET,
        Scope = SCOPE,
        Callback = callbackURL,
        SignatureMethod = "HMAC-SHA1"
    };

    OAuthUtil.GetUnauthorizedRequestToken(parameters);
    string authorizationUrl = OAuthUtil.CreateUserAuthorizationUrl(parameters);
    Session["parameters"] = parameters;
    ViewBag.AuthUrl = authorizationUrl;
    return View();
}

public ActionResult List()
{
    if (Session["parameters"] != null)
    {
        OAuthParameters parameters = Session["parameters"] as OAuthParameters;
        OAuthUtil.UpdateOAuthParametersFromCallback(Request.Url.Query, parameters);

        try
        {
            OAuthUtil.GetAccessToken(parameters);

            GOAuthRequestFactory authFactory = new GOAuthRequestFactory("writely", APPLICATION_NAME, parameters);

            var service = new DocumentsService(authFactory.ApplicationName);
            service.RequestFactory = authFactory;

            var query = new DocumentsListQuery();
            //query.Title = "recipe";

            var feed = service.Query(query);
            var docs = new List<string>();
            foreach (DocumentEntry entry in feed.Entries)
            {
                docs.Add(entry.Title.Text);
            }
            //var result = feed.Entries.ToList().ConvertAll(a => a.Title.Text);
            return View(docs);
        }
        catch (GDataRequestException gdre)
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)gdre.Response;

            //bad auth token, clear session and refresh the page
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
            {
                Session.Clear();
                Response.Write(gdre.Message);
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("Error processing request: " + gdre.ToString());
            }
            throw;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

[This 2-legged sample](http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/trunk/clients/cs/samples/OAuth/Program.cs) never worked for me for google docs.

Comment: If the 3-legged one works, just mark your own answer as "the answer".

Comment: @Christophe Geers: I am very well aware of that. I have spent quite a bit time here. Answering one own question will be active only after two days as of now :)

Comment: Ok, my bad. Did not know of the 2-day delay yet.

Answer (score 1):

You need to request a token from Google and use it to intialize your DocumentsService instance.

Here's an example using Google's ContactsService. It should be the same for the DocumentsService.

```
Service service = new ContactsService("My Contacts Application");
service.setUserCredentials("your_email_address_here@gmail.com", "yourpassword");
var token = service.QueryClientLoginToken();
service.SetAuthenticationToken(token);
```

But as you mentioned, you are using AuthSub. I jumped the gun a bit too fast.

I see that you are requesting a session token. According to the documentation of the API you must use the session token to authenticate requests to the service by placing the token in the Authorization header. After you've set the session token, you can use the Google Data APIs client library.

Here's a complete example (by Google) on how to use AuthSub with the .NET client library:

http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/apis/gdata/articles/authsub_dotnet.html

Let me include a shortened example:

```
GAuthSubRequestFactory authFactory = 
    new GAuthSubRequestFactory("cl", "TesterApp");
authFactory.Token = (String) Session["token"];
CalendarService service = new CalendarService(authFactory.ApplicationName);
service.RequestFactory = authFactory;

EventQuery query = new EventQuery();

query.Uri = new Uri("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full");

EventFeed calFeed = service.Query(query);
foreach (Google.GData.Calendar.EventEntry entry in calFeed.Entries)
{
    //...
}
```

And if I see correctly your example code pretty follows the same steps, except that you set the ConsumerKey and ConsumerSecret for the AuthFactory which is not done in the example by Google.

Comment: Another example of using AuthSub in C# can be found here: http://www.dotnetethics.com/2008/09/signin-using-google-account.html Seems to follow the same steps as yours.